# MAMP: Share database across 2 computers on same network

Tags: mysql, networking, mamp, sharing

How would I go about sharing a MySQL database in MAMP across 2 machines on the same network? I'm guessing there are some file permissions and network settings that would need to be configured to accomplish this. I just haven't came across a good tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: I guess that you want to avoid the Master/Slave replication thing. So there's some files to be shared and configuration files to be changed. Never tried that approach, though. You might want to check "how to move one db to another server", as well.

Answer (score 0):

To allow remote access to your mysql server, you need to change the `bind-address`, default is to only allow connections from localhost, to allow connection from all networkcards, just un comment that row in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`